# Can I implement 'function balance()' in a contract?

Tags: solidity

Can I do this?:

```
contract MyContract {
    uint256 myVar;
    function balance() external view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        return (address(this).balance, myVar);
    }
}
```

Both `solc` and `truffle compile` compile it successfully (i.e., no errors or warnings).

So I'm guessing that there's no problem here.

But I just want to be sure that it doesn't somehow "override" `address(this).balance`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
address(this).balance
```

Here, balance is a member function of the `address` type. The function above is a function of your contract. Nothing to fear.